# How do I display the output from the stripe api retrieve paymentintent in php?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

The stripe documentation only shows the way to retrieve the paymentintent and shows the ecpectected output but does not show what to echo. This is the code.

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_test_your_key');
$stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve(
  'pi_1Gszs62eZvKYlo2CvSLiQkTP',
  []
);
```

from here how would I output information such as shipping address and customer email; which are part of the expected output?
I am trying to retrieve the customer details right after purchase on the conformation page.

I have tried to echo and var_dump $paymentIntents but it returns as an undefined variable. I var_dump $stripe and just get the object itself and not the output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be setting the result to a variable anywhere, like this:

```
$paymentIntent = $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve(...)
```

You can explore the Payment Intent object [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object) to find the `shipping` details ([ref](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object?lang=curl#payment_intent_object-shipping)), and `customer` or `receipt_email` depending on the details of your integration. If you need the customer object details, you'd need to either retrieve that by ID too, or use [expansion](https://stripe.com/docs/expand) when retrieving the payment intent.